# Facebook API 3.0. - Add bundle information to image upload

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using FB API 3.0 for Android, and according to examples for Session I use

```
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback();
```

to upload the image. 
I need to add some default text to this image, but I can't figure out where to put it.

In old API there was a bundle of parameters that were sent:

```
params.putByteArray("picture", imgData);
params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
params.putString("caption", MyGlobals.INSTANCE.activeSetting.f_name);
```

What is the proper way to add text to Request for newUploadPhotoRequest?

tnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After you create the request and before you execute it, you can do the following:

```
// Get the current parameters for the request
Bundle params = request.getParameters();
// Add the parameters you want, the caption in this case
params.putString("name", "My Caption String");
// Update the request parameters
request.setParameters(params);

// Execute the request
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the above solution we are unable to add description to image.

Solution:

replace `name` with `message` Because:

```
params.putString("name", "My Caption String");
```

`putString` first parameter is key for `My caption String` that key is unique one that unique was taken as `message`.