# Android - How do I set the video's title or description

Tags: android, facebook, video

I use Facebook SDK 3.0. And try to upload video to Facebook. 
My video uploads if I use:

```
request = Request.newUploadVideoRequest(session, new File(
                    dataPath), callback);
```

How is it possible to set the title?
Could anyone help me?

Comment: I am sure there are webservices for it. Havn't you researched enough ?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I've tried like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083419/facebook-api-3-0-add-bundle-information-to-image-upload but for video. And I got (#353) Missing video file. But without setting parameters everything is ok.

Comment: No, I haven't. I haven't heard about it. Thank you, I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (after you create the request):

```
Bundle params = request.getParameters();
params.putString("title", yourTitle);
params.putString("description", yourDescription);
// you may need to do a request.setParameters(params); 
request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for webservices work, you must use a tool like fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp). Once you identify the webservices that you need and their return values, you can start with code. Dont do the other way around, a lot more unnecessary work.